# How does an "auto-installer" for big php scripts work?

Tags: php, installation

I am looking at an easy way for users to install and in future update their copies of my software.

At this stage I haven't tried anything, and am not looking for code, just Ideas, Issues and past experiences of anyone that has built installers/updaters for their app's.

**What I am thinking is;**

User will download a very base of the system, that will container an installer file, and a couple of the base directories that are needed.

They will have to set read/write permissions to each directory and then run the installer.
This will then download and create all of the files needed to run the system.

The user should then delete the installer files.

In future when they log on to the administration, the system will see if there is an update released, and then upon clicking a link, lock the site, and the system will update itself, then open the site back up.

**Obvious issues:**

Giving PHP write access to the site allows hacking attempts and the possibility for malicious files to be installed then run.

I know Wordpress has updating functionality built with PHP FTP classes, and this could be an option.

Comment: So what's your question? And if your answer to that is "How do I do it?", my next question is going to be "What have you tried?".

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions for information on writing good questions.

Comment: Thanks Kristian, Its a question asking for advice, not how, and I haven't tried anything yet. I'm just looking for ideas at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Download some common scripts (wordpress, joomla, login scripts, etc) that have an auto-installer and look into the code ! Usually it's something like:

1. check for files/folders/rights
2. ask for db connection/users/pw
3. check for dbs right
4. create (& fill) db, write some configs
5. move/delete files

Quite simple stuff. But makes it very easy for non-programmers to handle the product.